# How to get multiple hosts configuration and database cluster failover

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

In java we had an option to use multiple hosts configuration with failover mechanism:

```
jdbc:postgresql://node1:port1,node2:port2,node3:port3/accounting?targetServerType=primary
```

do we have such support in Go? How the connection string should look like? i've seen that lib/pq [is not maintained](https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/800)

i didn't find any information about [jackc/pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) if they support multi host, or how the connection string should look like. Please if someone can provide an example.

Comment: Such support is not built into the standard library, no.